# How do I add square root function to my calculator?

Tags: android, calculator, square-root

I made this calculator app for android. It takes in a number, operator then another number. I've tried adding a square root function to it but it either doesn't work or it crashes. The main issue is that the operator cannot be entered before the number and the square root operator requires a number after it so I removed the square root for now. How can I fix this? I've added my code below.`public class Calculator extends AppCompatActivity {

```
private TextView _screen;
private String display = "";
private String currentOperator = "";
private String result = "";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_calculator);

    _screen = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
    _screen.setText(display);
}

private void updateScreen() {

    _screen.setText(display);

}

public void onClickNumber(View view) {

    if (result != "") {

        clear();
        updateScreen();

    }

    Button b = (Button) view;
    display += b.getText();
    updateScreen();

}

public void onClickDecimal(View view) {

    if (result != "") {

        clear();
        updateScreen();

    }

    Button b = (Button) view;
    display += b.getText();
    updateScreen();

}

public void onClickBackspace(View view) {

    int length = display.length();

    if (length >= 1) {

        display = display.substring(0, length - 1);
        updateScreen();

    }

    else {

        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(this, "Please enter some numbers first", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        toast.show();

    }

}

private boolean isOperator(char op) {

    switch (op) {

        case '+':
            return true;

        case '-':
            return true;

        case 'x':
            return true;

        case '÷':
            return true;

        case '%':
            return true;

        case '^':
            return true;

        case '√':
            return true;

        default:
            return false;

    }

}

public void onClickOperator(View view) {

    if (display == "") return;

    Button b = (Button) view;


    if (result != "") {

        String _display = result;
        clear();
        display = _display;

    }

    if (currentOperator != "") {

        if (isOperator(display.charAt(display.length() - 1))) {

            display = display.replace(display.charAt(display.length() - 1), b.getText().charAt(0));
            updateScreen();
            return;

        }

        else {

            getResult();
            display = result;
            result = "";

        }

        currentOperator = b.getText().toString();

    }

    display += b.getText();
    currentOperator = b.getText().toString();
    updateScreen();

}

private void clear() {

    display = "";
    currentOperator = "";
    result = "";

}

public void onClickClear(View view) {

    clear();
    updateScreen();

}

private double operate(String a, String b, String op) {

    switch (op) {

        case "+":
            return Double.valueOf(a) + Double.valueOf(b);

        case "-":
            return Double.valueOf(a) - Double.valueOf(b);

        case "x":
            return Double.valueOf(a) * Double.valueOf(b);

        case "÷":
            return Double.valueOf(a) / Double.valueOf(b);

        case "%":
            return Double.valueOf(a) % Double.valueOf(b);

        case "^":
            return Math.pow(Double.valueOf(a), Double.valueOf(b));

        case "√":
            return Math.sqrt(Double.valueOf(a));

        default:
            return -1;


    }

}

private boolean getResult() {

    DecimalFormat res = new DecimalFormat("#,###,###,###.######");

    if (currentOperator == "") return false;

    String[] operation = display.split(Pattern.quote(currentOperator));

    if (operation.length < 2) return false;

            result = String.valueOf(res.format(operate(operation[0], operation[1], currentOperator)));

    return true;

}

public void onClickEquals(View view) {

    int length = result.length();

    if (display == "") return;

    if(!getResult()) return;

    if (length <= 10) {

        _screen.setText(String.valueOf(result));

    }

    else {

        result = result.substring(0, 9);
        _screen.setText(String.valueOf(result));

    }

}`
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:-

```
double x = 2.45;
System.out.printf("sqrt(%.3f) is %.3f%n", x, Math.sqrt(x));
```

Result:-

```
sqrt(2.45) is 1.565
```

Comment: How can I implement this to work perfectly with my code since it requires a number before the operator which isn't possible in this case?